# Namespace, use reach file one folder up

Tags: php, namespaces

Im trying to reach a class file where I have defined namespace in the top with the following:
File: config.php

```
namespace Config;

class Config
{
    // Stuffs
}
```

The file structure is like this

```
public_html
- admin
-- header.php
-- footer.php
-- file-trying-to-reach-config.php
- config.php
```

Im trying to reach the config.php -file from the file-trying-to-reach-config.php. In the top of file-trying-to-reach-config.php Im using:

```
use \Config;
```

But I have no clue how I, with use move up on folder to reach config.php. Googled and Stacked but didn't find anything about it. Have I misunderstood the concept with namespace and use?

How do I reach config.php with use from file-trying-to-reach-config.php?

Comment: Namespaces are ***not*** to create dir structures (although often abused that way, or the other way around). You should define an autoload function, so you'll just be able to use `\Config\Config` (which seems weird to want) without having to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Use` operator is used to alias namespaces in PHP, as described in [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). This essentially gives you the ability to create short names for classes when you have complex namespaces.

You need to either [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) the config.php file into where you want to call it. e.g.

```
<?php

   include_once('../config.php');
   $config = new \Config\Config();
```

For a more advanced way to handle this, you can look into [Autoloading](http://www.php.net/autoload) which will do the include bit automagically.